# How could I calculate this sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Could you please help me to calculate this finite sum ?
\begin{align}
S=\sum _{n=1}^{\text{Nmax}} n*P^n
\end{align}
 where $P\leq  1$ and  $\text{Nmax}>1$.

Comment: Have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=P.\sum_{n=1}^N nP^{n-1}=P.\frac{d}{dP}\sum_{n=1}^NP^n=P.\frac{d}{dP}\frac{P(1-P^N)}{1-P}$$ So $$S=\frac{(1-P)(1-(N+1)P^N)+P(1-P^N)}{(1-P)^2}$$

Simplify to get the answer.

Another way to do this ( and this does not need derivatives ) is

$$S=1.P+2.P^2+3.P^3\cdots +(N-1)P^{N-1}+N.P^N$$
Now $$S.P=1.P^2+2.P^3\cdots+(N-1)P^N+(N+1)P^{N+1}$$
So $$S-SP=P+P^2+P^3+\cdots+P^N+(N+1)P^{N+1}$$
Which implies $$S(1-P)=\frac{P(1-P^N)}{1-P}+(N+1)P^{N+1}$$
Now simplify to get the value of $S$

Answer (score 3):

1. Start from the geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nx^n=x\dfrac{1-x^N}{1-x}$.
2. Differentiate both sides to get an expression of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nnx^{n-1}$.
3. Multiply the result by $x$ to deduce $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nnx^{n}$.